# .Net Core 2.0 Visual Studio Code Debug mode

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

When I am launchin debug of asp.net project, it open Edge where

> Can’t connect securely to this page This might be because the site
>   uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps
>   happening, try contacting the website’s owner. Try this: Go back to
>   the last page

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Try to use different browser. It may be a problem with IE, Edge browsers as discussed [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows_10/cant-connect-securely-to-this-page/e9453552-6f7e-43ef-9374-a424930e4c9c)

Comment: Are you running HTTPS?

Comment: Did you come up with a solution? I have the same issue here.

Comment: @Richard, I created project without authentication.